Listing of the Meraglim
I’m curious as to why in Bamidbar 13 the Meraglim are listed in the order that they are, as opposed to in age descending order like the shevatim are usually referred to (or at least age descending of Leah and Rachel first and then Bilhah and Zilpah)

Iirc the Artscroll chumash says it was in descending order of greatness.

See Ramban on verse 4 that addresses this question. I’ve cited below from Sefaria both Hebrew and English text for reference:

למטה ראובן וגו' מנה הכתוב השבטים לא לדגליהם ולא לצבאותם ולא כתולדותם
ונראה שראה למנותם הנה לפי מעלת השלוחים כי היו ראשים ונשיאים בעם כאשר
ספר ואין מעלתם שוה אבל יש בהם גדול מחברו בחכמה (ובמנין) ובכבוד והקדים
הנכבד הקודם במעלה כי ממעלת עצמם מנאם לא למעלת השבט וכן בנשיאים החולקים
להם את ארץ כנען (להלן לד יז-כט) הזכירם כפי המעלה לא לתולדותם:
OF THE TRIBE OF REUBEN etc. The verse [here] lists the tribes neither
according to [the pattern of encampment of] their standards, nor
according to the order of birth [of the ancestors of each tribe]. It
appears that Scripture saw fit to mention them here according to the
importance of the delegates [on the mission], for they were heads and
princes of the people, as is related, but they were not all of equal
standing, some of them being greater than the others in wisdom and
honor; therefore Scripture mentioned first those who were most
honored, who were first in status, since it named them according to
their personal standing, not that of their tribe. Similarly in [citing
the names of] the princes who were to divide the Land up amongst the
people, He mentioned them according to their personal standing, not
according to the order of birth [of the tribal ancestors].

The Netziv, Haamek Davar, explains further that this does not mean just in reference to Torah but rather wisdom in their task (I.e scouting the land and devising plan for war).

למטה ראובן וגו׳. מונה והולך לא לפי סדר התולדה ולא לפי הדגלים. אלא לפי
חשיבות השלוחים. וכ״כ הרמב״ן. וכיב״ז אי׳ בדה״י א׳ ט״ו שמנה דוד המלך
ראשי הלוים מכל משפחה והקדים מררי לגרשום. וע״כ משום דערכי ראשי מררי היה
אז גדול מראשי גרשום. כך הוא סדר פרשה זו. אמנם חשיבות בזה הענין לא היה
תלוי בתורה ויראת ה׳ ובמעלה כמש״כ הרמב״ן אלא בהכשר ויתרון דעת השליחות
לדעת הדרך והערים שראוי להחל בהם המלחמה:
For the tribe of Reuven. The Torah counts them by the importance of
the messengers. However, their importance in this matter was not
dependent on Torah, fear of Hashem and virtue, but rather on their
ability and advanced knowledge in the task for which they were sent —
to discover the way and which cities should be attacked first in the
war.

This explains why Yehoshua was not mentioned first despite him being the disciple of Moshe

Several other commentators like Haamek Davar, Sforno, Tur HaAruch and more also comment on this

Interesting. How is it possible though that Yehoshua who was Moshe’s disciple was on a lower level then some of the other spies and not mentioned first?

Good question. The Netziv, Haamek Davar, says למטה ראובן וגו׳. מונה והולך לא לפי סדר התולדה ולא לפי הדגלים. אלא לפי חשיבות השלוחים. וכ״כ הרמב״ן. וכיב״ז אי׳ בדה״י א׳ ט״ו שמנה דוד המלך ראשי הלוים מכל משפחה והקדים מררי לגרשום. וע״כ משום דערכי ראשי מררי היה אז גדול מראשי גרשום. כך הוא סדר פרשה זו. אמנם חשיבות בזה הענין לא היה תלוי בתורה ויראת ה׳ ובמעלה כמש״כ הרמב״ן אלא בהכשר ויתרון דעת השליחות לדעת הדרך והערים שראוי להחל בהם המלחמה:

Translation: For the tribe of Reuven. The Torah counts them by the importance of the messengers. However, their importance in this matter was not dependent on Torah, fear of Hashem and virtue, but rather on their ability and advanced knowledge in the task for which they were sent — to discover the way and which cities should be attacked first in the war.

@CuriousYid Why does the fact that he was Moshe's disciple mean that he must be greater than everyone else?

@ShtikaK'hodaah great thanks!
